# iOS webview javascript focus next field

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, focus

I have been stucked up in a simple but strange issue from last 8 hours

I am using a UIWebView. 
I am albe to set text in the text field of the website by using

```
  activeItem=document.activeElement; 
  if(activeItem.type != undefined){activeItem.value="BlahBlah!"};
```

Now i want to focus on next text field of the web page (The same function as the iOS Keyboard Next/Previous buttons does but programmatically ) after the text field value is set to BlahBlah!

I have tried the following one;

```
  myfields=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type='password']");
  myItem=myfields.item(0);
  myItem.focus();
  myItem.scrollIntoView();
```

But cursor is not moving to the next field.

Using iOS 7 and 6 but no luck.
Please help!!!!!!!!!